# On the definition of exhaustion functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I'll first express **my confusion：why can the exhaustion function  of a  domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ be bounded?**

More precisely:

In p. 45 of the book *Partial differential equations in several complex variables*   by  Chen S C and Shaw M C. , the author give the definition of the exhaustion function as follows:

Definition 3.4.6. A function $\varphi: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on an open subset $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called an **exhaustion function** for $D$ if for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x \in D \mid \varphi(x)<c\}$ is relatively compact.

Then one can easily see from the definition of relatively compactness that **when the point tends to the boundary of $D$, $\varphi$ tends to $+\infty$.**

However, in p. 49, the author give a well-known theorem that there always exists a **bounded** strictly plurisubharmonic **exhaustion function** on any smooth bounded pseudoconvex domain:

Theorem 3.4.12. Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}^n, n \geq 2$, be a smooth bounded pseudoconvex domain. Let $r$ be a smooth defining function for $D$. Then there exist constants $K>0$ and $0<\eta_0<1$, such that for any $\eta$ with $0<\eta \leq \eta_0, \rho=-\left(-r e^{-K|z|^2}\right)^\eta$ is a smooth bounded strictly plurisubharmonic exhaustion function on $D$.

> I restate **my confusion**：**why can the exhaustion function  of a
>
> domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ be bounded?  Did I misunderstand something
>
> somewhere?** (p.s. I am very sure that Theorem 3.4.12. is right and
> well-known)

Feel free to share your thoughts – all input  are welcome!

Comment: Assuming you are quoting the book correctly, they goofed. This happens.

Comment: There are two type of exhaustion function. One is bounded another one is unbounded. In the definition of bounded exhaustion function we want want $\{f<c\}$ to be relatively compact where $c<\sup_Df.$

Comment: @Biplab  Great, thank you， I think what you're saying is the point.